# What is best practice to implement a HTTP POST to cope with server timout?

Tags: spring, http, post, timeout

I am writing a REST service where the result of a REST POST can take longer than the environments timeout settings for HTTP connections. Given that I can't change the timeout for my REST target url, 
What can I do to to make a REST call pass properly? I thought about using an async controller, but that seems not to fix any timeout behavior.

The calling client should not have to handle any server error or try to re-execute the query, as it is just adding more stress to the server.

Cheers,
Kai

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a connection read timeout and not a http keepalive timeout since there is only one query. One suggestion would be for the rest service to return intermittent status response every specified interval. If this is a tcp keepalive issue then it can be circumvented using configuration. If a socket read timeout is being set then thst can be increased as well.

Comment: I thought something like that, sending a location to a temporary url, then 202 until the backend process is complete. but does the usual rest client handle that? does jquery.ajax wait and repeat until RC 200 has been served?

Comment: instead of 202, can the backend process periodically return a predefined string to be ignored by the client till the response can be returned? How about TCP KeepAlive, do you know the reason for the connection read timeout - perhaps a HTTP keepalive setting or a TCP keepalive?

Comment: TCP keepalive is too lowlevel, we are implementing a REST service here, we have not access to anything before the Spring controller. Also, the loadbalancer/proxy and other elements between the client and the server might ignore that as well.

Comment: Why would they ignore that?